# Modifying yaml array in bash

Tags: yq

I have a file with below content,

```
- groups:
  - system:bootstrappers
  - system:nodes
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::1234566:role/radeks-project-us-east-1-NodeInstanceRole
  username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
```

I want to append this file content as shown below with eks ,iammappings as first two lines,

```
eks:
  iammappings:
  - groups:
  - system:bootstrappers
  - system:nodes
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::1234566:role/radeks-project-us-east-1-NodeInstanceRole
  username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
```

I tried yq merge.But It didnt work for me.Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Try: cat file2 >> file1

Comment: But I need to add eks: ,iammappings as parents yaml tags to the array

Comment: FYI, all JSON files are also valid YAML files. Even if your _input_ is formatted in a way that's conventional YAML, it'll work perfectly fine if your _output_ is just JSON -- which means you have a much wider array of tools that can write it.

Comment: ...and are you _sure_ your stated output is right? The way you state it, `groups` is the key in a dictionary whose value is `null`, and `system:bootstrappers` and `system:nodes` are not inside `groups`, but instead are separate items in the `iammappings` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific tool for parsing yaml in bash i.e `yq` same as `jq`.
Link - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

You have to modify the source yaml file as follows

```
- groups:
    - system:bootstrappers
    - system:nodes
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::1234566:role/radeks-project-us-east-1-NodeInstanceRole
    - username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
```

Else `yq` won't accept it as proper yaml file.

Next to get your job done use the following command

```
yq p -i file.yaml 'eks.iammappings'
```

The above command uses `prefix` function and will replace in place. The contents of the file will be as follows

```
eks:
  iammappings:
    - groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
        - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::1234566:role/radeks-project-us-east-1-NodeInstanceRole
        - username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
```

Comment: Incidentally, the OP already knows about `yq` -- they asked a question about its use just this morning.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy He didn't try `yq` prefix